# Drawing and Labeling a Triangle for a Demonstration of the Double-Angle Formula of Cosines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a display of two triangles, but the triangle drawn in red is unintentional.  `TikZ` is misinterpreting the coordinates for point `C`.  The polar coordinates for `C` is given as `\coordinate (C) at (120:5);`.  `TikZ` is plotting the point in Quadrant III.

Also, `TikZ` is misinterpreting the positions at which I want the label for the vertex `A` and the labels for the angles to be typeset.  The command to place `A` is

`\node at ({2.5mm*sqrt(2)/2},{-2.5mm*sqrt(2)/2}){$A$};`

and the commands to place `$\theta$` are

`\coordinate (label_for_theta) at (60:4mm);`

`\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_theta){$\theta$};`.

It seems to me that `TikZ` is placing these labels using the canvas coordinate system.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-1.5,ymax=5,
    restrict y to domain=-1.5:5,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

%A triangle is drawn on the Cartesian plane. One side of the triangle is along
%the positive x-axis, and another side of the triangle is drawn in Quadrant II.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3.5,0);
\coordinate (C) at (120:5);
\draw[red] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%The labels for A and B are typeset.
\node at ({2.5mm*sqrt(2)/2}:{-2.5mm*sqrt(2)/2}){$A$};
\node at (3.5,-2.5mm){$B$};

%The point C' = C is placed using Cartesian coordinates.
\coordinate (C') at (-2.5,{5*sin(120)});
\draw[fill] (C') circle (1.5pt);
\draw (A) -- (C');
\draw (B) -- (C');
%The label for C' = C is typeset.
\coordinate (label_C_left) at ($(C')!-4mm!(B)$);
\coordinate (label_C_right) at ($(C')!-4mm!(A)$);
\coordinate (label_C) at ($(label_C_left)!0.5!(label_C_right)$);
\node[blue] at ($(C')!2.5mm!(label_C)$){$C$};

%Angles are drawn for $\theta$ and its supplement.
\draw[draw=blue] (A) ++(120:4mm) arc (120:0:4mm);
\coordinate (label_for_theta) at (60:6.5mm);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_theta){$\theta$};
\draw[draw=blue,dash dot] (A) ++(180:6mm) arc (180:120:6mm);
\coordinate (label_for_supplement_to_theta) at (150:8.5mm);
\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_supplement_to_theta){$\pi - \theta$};


%A right-angle mark is drawn.
\coordinate (U) at ($(-2.5,0)!3mm!45:(A)$);
\draw[dash dot] (U) -- ($(-2.5,0)!(U)!(A)$);
\draw[dash dot] (U) -- ($(-2.5,0)!(U)!(C')$);


\draw[dashed] (C') -- (-2.5,0);

%Braces indicating the distances that C' is from the axes are typeset. To give
%them the appearance of being typeset over the axes, they are first typeset
%in white with a line width of 2pt, which is 10 times the thickness of the
%brace that is actually typeset.
\draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt}] (-2.5,0) -- (C');
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt}] (-2.5,0) -- (C');
\draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-2.5,0) -- (A);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-2.5,0) -- (A);


\coordinate (label_for_5_sin_theta) at ($({5*cos(120)},{2.5*sin(120)}) + (-2.5mm-10pt,0pt)$);
\node[anchor=east] at (label_for_5_sin_theta){$r\sin\theta$};
\coordinate (label_for_5_cos_theta) at (-1.25,-2.5mm-10pt);
\node at (label_for_5_cos_theta){$r\cos\theta$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I see C in quadrant II (upper left).

Comment: @John Kormylo  It looks like that.  I correctly put `C` there with the command `\coordinate (C') at (-2.5,{5*sin(120)});`.

Comment: Is this really minimal? For example, why do you need multiple examples of coordinates being misplaced? Isn't one enough?

Comment: Your example needs to demonstrate the problem....

Comment: @cfr   The `A`, `\theta`, and `\pi - \theta` are obviously in the wrong place.  Also, the command `\draw[red] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;` should draw a triangle in Quadrant III.  It does when my computer compiles the code.

Comment: @John Kormylo  The `A`, `\theta`, and `\pi - \theta` are obviously in the wrong place.  Also, the command `\draw[red] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;` should draw a triangle in Quadrant III.  It does when my computer compiles the code.

Comment: Did you see the [image @JohnKormylo posted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/C89u8.png)?

Comment: @cfr  Yeah, I wasn't allowed to respond to his post.  Don't know what happened.

Comment: You responded, then I deleted the "answer."  I don't know how to post images in comments.

Comment: @John Kormylo  OK.

Comment: Which is Quadrant III? (Not familiar with the terminology.) `C` and `C'` are co-located.  A really minimal example would make this a whole lot easier - it may be obvious to you, but figuring out what you expect the code to do etc. is much less so to others.

Comment: @JohnKormylo You can post a link. I put the image as-if-in-an-answer, get the link, cancel the answer and then post the link in the comment. Maybe there is a more elegant method but this one works.

Comment: I think that you cannot use dimensions when specifying polar coordinates. So don't say `60:4mm` but something like `60:0.4`.

Comment: @cfr  Quadrant III are those points with polar coordinates like (\theta:r) for 180 < \theta < 270.  I have `\coordinate (C) at (120:5);` and `\coordinate (C') at (-2.5,{5*sin(120)});`.  They should be put in the same spot, but the one given in polar coordinates is misplaced.

Comment: @cfr  I have placed nodes in other `tikzpicture` environments using polar coordinates and specifying the length of the radius in units of `pt`.

Comment: C and C' are in the same place. Neither is in Quadrant III.

Comment: @crf  Type the command `\draw[fill,red] (C) circle (1.5pt);`.  You will see that the circle at `C` is in Quadrant III.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot straightforwardly use dimensions when specifying coordinates within an `axis` environment. Since the specification for `C` doesn't use a dimension, it is correctly placed, but other coordinates are misplaced relative to the intended origin.

To see that this is not an effect of TikZ itself, simply remove the `axis` environment and typeset the remaining code within the raw `tikzpicture` environment.

The reason this does not work in the `axis` environment is because there is, in general, no one-one correspondence between the coordinate systems used by TikZ and those configured by `pgfplots`. See page 350, section 4.27 TikZ Interoperability for details.

One option is to simply dispense with `pgfplots` as you are not really using it except to draw the axes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [{Latex[]}-{Latex[]}] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below right] {$x$};
  \draw [{Latex[]}-{Latex[]}] (0,-1.5) -- (0,5.5) node [above right] {$y$};

  %A triangle is drawn on the Cartesian plane. One side of the triangle is along
  %the positive x-axis, and another side of the triangle is drawn in Quadrant II.
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3.5,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (120:5);
  \draw[draw=red] (A) node [below right] {$A$} -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

  %The label for B is typeset.
  \node at (3.5,-2.5mm){$B$};

  %The point C' = C is placed using Cartesian coordinates.
  \coordinate (C') at (-2.5,{5*sin(120)});
  \draw[fill] (C') circle (1.5pt);
  \draw (A) -- (C');
  \draw (B) -- (C');
  %The label for C' = C is typeset.
  \coordinate (label_C_left) at ($(C')!-4mm!(B)$);
  \coordinate (label_C_right) at ($(C')!-4mm!(A)$);
  \coordinate (label_C) at ($(label_C_left)!0.5!(label_C_right)$);
  \node[blue] at ($(C')!2.5mm!(label_C)$){$C$};

  %Angles are drawn for $\theta$ and its supplement.
  \draw[draw=blue] (A) ++(120:4mm) arc (120:0:4mm);
  \coordinate (label_for_theta) at (60:6mm);
  \node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_theta){$\theta$};
  \draw[draw=blue,dash dot] (A) ++(180:6mm) arc (180:120:6mm);
  \coordinate (label_for_supplement_to_theta) at (150:9.5mm);
  \node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_supplement_to_theta){$\pi - \theta$};

  %A right-angle mark is drawn.
  \coordinate (U) at ($(-2.5,0)!3mm!45:(A)$);
  \draw[dash dot] (U) -- ($(-2.5,0)!(U)!(A)$);
  \draw[dash dot] (U) -- ($(-2.5,0)!(U)!(C')$);

  \draw[dashed] (C') -- (-2.5,0);

  %Braces indicating the distances that C' is from the axes are typeset. To give
  %them the appearance of being typeset over the axes, they are first typeset
  %in white with a line width of 2pt, which is 10 times the thickness of the
  %brace that is actually typeset.
  \draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt}] (-2.5,0) -- (C');
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt}] (-2.5,0) -- (C');
  \draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-2.5,0) -- (A);
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-2.5,0) -- (A);

  \coordinate (label_for_5_sin_theta) at ($({5*cos(120)},{2.5*sin(120)}) + (-2.5mm-10pt,0pt)$);
  \node[anchor=east] at (label_for_5_sin_theta){$r\sin\theta$};
  \coordinate (label_for_5_cos_theta) at (-1.25,-2.5mm-10pt);
  \node at (label_for_5_cos_theta){$r\cos\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: non-plotted axes]

Another option is to specify the coordinates differently. Although polar coordinates using absolute dimensions do not work within the `axis` environment you've defined, specifying them without using absolute dimensions does:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-1.5,ymax=5,
    restrict y to domain=-1.5:5,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]

    %A triangle is drawn on the Cartesian plane. One side of the triangle is along
    %the positive x-axis, and another side of the triangle is drawn in Quadrant II.
    \draw [draw= red] (0,0) coordinate (A) node [below right] {$A$} -- (3.5,0) coordinate (B) node [below] {$B$} -- (120:5) coordinate (C) -- cycle;

    %The point C' = C is placed using Cartesian coordinates.
    \draw (A) --  (-2.5,{5*sin(120)}) coordinate (C') -- (B);
    \draw[fill] (C') circle (1.5pt);
    %The label for C' = C is typeset.
    \coordinate (label_C_left) at ($(C')!-4mm!(B)$);
    \coordinate (label_C_right) at ($(C')!-4mm!(A)$);
    \coordinate (label_C) at ($(label_C_left)!0.5!(label_C_right)$);
    \node[blue] at ($(C')!2.5mm!(label_C)$){$C$};

    %Angles are drawn for $\theta$ and its supplement.
    \draw[draw=blue] (120:0.4) arc (120:0:0.4);
    \coordinate (label_for_theta) at (60:0.4);
    \node[font=\footnotesize, anchor=south west] at (label_for_theta){$\theta$};
    \draw[draw=blue,dash dot] (180:.6) arc (180:120:.6);
    \coordinate (label_for_supplement_to_theta) at (150:.6);
    \node[font=\footnotesize, anchor=south east] at (label_for_supplement_to_theta){$\pi - \theta$};

    %A right-angle mark is drawn.
    \draw[dash dot] ($(-2.5,0)!3mm!45:(A)$) coordinate (U) -- ($(-2.5,0)!(U)!(A)$);
    \draw[dash dot] (U) -- ($(-2.5,0)!(U)!(C')$);

    \draw[dashed] (C') -- (-2.5,0);

    %Braces indicating the distances that C' is from the axes are typeset. To give
    %them the appearance of being typeset over the axes, they are first typeset
    %in white with a line width of 2pt, which is 10 times the thickness of the
    %brace that is actually typeset.
    \draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt}] (-2.5,0) -- (C');
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt}] (-2.5,0) -- (C');
    \draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-2.5,0) -- (A);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-2.5,0) -- (A);

    \coordinate (label_for_5_sin_theta) at ($({5*cos(120)},{2.5*sin(120)}) + (-2.5mm-10pt,0pt)$);
    \node[anchor=east] at (label_for_5_sin_theta){$r\sin\theta$};
    \coordinate (label_for_5_cos_theta) at (-1.25,-2.5mm-10pt);
    \node at (label_for_5_cos_theta){$r\cos\theta$};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: non-dimensions in polar coordinates]

It is true that you can usually use dimensions to say e.g. `(60:6mm)` in an ordinary `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: You have `$\p - \theta$` in the wrong place.  Yes, this is the display (or close to the display) that I wanted.  The reason for my post was to ask for an explanation for `TikZ` misinterpreting the command `\node at ({2.5mm*sqrt(2)/2},{-2.5mm*sqrt(2)/2}){$A$};` to place the label `A` and the two commands `\coordinate (label_for_theta) at (60:4mm);` and `\node[font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_theta){$\theta$};` to place the label `$\theta$`.

Comment: Yep.  The second position should be `(150:6mm)`. (I will edit the code.)  I replaced `6mm` with `0.6` and got something bizarre - elliptical with a major axis of about 10.

Comment: I will look at your code now.  I would prefer not to use the `axis` environment for such displays.  Can you tell me the exact position that the `x` is typeset in the command `xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west}` and the  exact position that the `y` is typeset in the command `ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}`?  I do not know what the manual is saying about `ticklabel*`.

Comment: As I said, I would like to remove the `axis` environment.  If I were to replace the x-axis in the `axis` environment with the command `\draw[latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0);`, what would I put for `blah` in the command `\node at (blah){$x$}`, and if I were to replace the y-axis in the `axis` environment with the command `\draw[latex-latex] (0,-5) -- (0,5);`, what would I put for `blah-blah` in the command `\node at (blah-blah){$y$}`?

Comment: What I would like to have in my code looks like this.   `\coordinate (x-label) at ($(5,0) +(x-shift,y-shift)$);` and `\node at (x-label){$x$};`. What would be the x-shift and y-shift?

Comment: In your code without the `axis` environment, replace what you have for placing the labels for the angles with `\coordinate (label_for_theta) at (60:6.5mm);` and `\coordinate (label_for_supplement_to_theta) at (150:8.5mm);`.  You are right - I did edit the code.  So, your display will be confusing to other users.  (I will delete this comment if you edit your first display.)

Comment: Sorry.  For the label `A`, use `anchor=northwest`, and for the angles, use `anchor=southeast` and `anchor=southwest`.

Comment: @user74973 It is just an example. It is designed to answer the question you asked. You can easily adjust the details as you wish. You shouldn't even be giving us this much code - it is far from minimal. People do not need to edit their answers to use precisely the specifications you finally decide upon. It is more than sufficient provided the answers explain the basics required to solve the problem or answer the question. The anchors used for `A` and the angles have nothing whatsoever to do with the original question. They are irrelevant. They don't matter. Forget them.

Comment: My question was about `A` being misplaced.  So, if your display shows `A` being misplaced, it will be confusing to other members.  (I understand what you meant.  I am also the one with whom you have been having the discussion.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26171/discussion-between-cfr-and-user74973).

Comment: @user74973 I've cleaned up somewhat here. I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  This is messy.  The coffee shop at which I am sitting is closing in 3 minutes.  I will send you a ping tomorrow to see whether you are available.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 5):

Is this the image you are after?

[image]

After all the discussions and conversations, I think you now got the idea why there were some points misplaced. In brief, that is because the axes are basically used for plotting data points (table) and not dimensions and lengths. So, some conversions are required, e.g., the dimension `6mm` may be entered `0.6`, etc.

So, my suggestion is to drop the axis environment all together (since you used it only for drawing two axes) and you can draw the axes with a single line of code as this:

```
\path[<->](0,5)edge(0,-1.5cm)node[above right]{$y$}  (5,0)edge(-5,0)node[below right]{$x$};
```

I also cleaned the code a bit and removed extra unneeded points:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,quotes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
% The axes:
\path[<->] (0,5)edge(0,-1.5cm)node[above right]{$y$}  (5,0)edge(-5,0)node[below right]{$x$};

%A triangle is drawn on the Cartesian plane. One side of the triangle is along the positive x-axis, and another side of the triangle is drawn in Quadrant II.
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) node[anchor=north west]{$A$}
(3.5,0)  coordinate (B) node[below]{$B$} 
(120:5)  coordinate (C) node[blue,above left]{$C$};
\draw[red] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;

%The point C' = C is placed using Cartesian coordinates.
\coordinate (C') at (-2.5,{5*sin(120)});
\draw[fill] (C') circle (1.5pt);
\draw (A) --(C');
\draw (B) --(C');

%Angles are drawn for $\theta$ and its supplement.
\draw[draw=blue] (120:4mm) arc (120:0:4mm);
\coordinate (label_for_theta) at (60:4mm);
\node[font=\footnotesize, anchor=south west] at (label_for_theta){$\theta$};
\draw[draw=blue,dash dot] (180:6mm) arc (180:120:6mm);
\coordinate (label_for_supplement_to_theta) at (150:6mm);
\node[font=\footnotesize,anchor=south east] at (label_for_supplement_to_theta){$\pi - \theta$};

%A right-angle mark is drawn.
\coordinate (U) at ($(-2.5,0)!3mm!45:(A)$);
\draw[dash dot] (U) -- ($(-2.5,0)!(U)!(A)$);
\draw[dash dot] (U) -- ($(-2.5,0)!(U)!(C')$);

\draw[dashed] (C') -- (-2.5,0);

% Braces indicating the distances that C' is from the axes are typeset. To give
% them the appearance of being typeset over the axes, they are first typeset
% in white with a line width of 2pt, which is 10 times the thickness of the
% brace that is actually typeset.
\draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=4pt,amplitude=5pt}] (-2.5,0) -- (C');
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt}] (-2.5,0) -- (C');
\draw[draw=white,line width=4pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=4pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-2.5,0) -- (A);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (-2.5,0) -- (A);

\coordinate (label_for_5_sin_theta) at ($({5*cos(120)},{2.5*sin(120)}) + (-2.5mm-10pt,0pt)$);
\node[anchor=east] at (label_for_5_sin_theta){$r\sin\theta$};
\coordinate (label_for_5_cos_theta) at (-1.25,-2.5mm-10pt);
\node at (label_for_5_cos_theta){$r\cos\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My recommendation, however,  is to use the specific packages and commands for your problem. Namely, `tkz-euclide` package is specialized in drawings like this. You will have the power to do many things easily with a single command like `\tkzMarkRightAngle(p1,p2,p3)`, for example, to mark a right angle. See this full documentation of the package [here](http://ctan.asis.io/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf) (in French).

Here is my implementation with `tkz-euclide` (observe how short and clean this is):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usetkzobj{all} % To have full access to the power of tikz-euclide
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
% The axes:
\path[<->] (0,5)edge(0,-1.5cm)node[above right]{$y$}  (5,0)edge(-5,0)node[below right]{$x$};    
% A triangle is drawn on the Cartesian plane. One side of the triangle is along
% the positive x-axis, and another side of the triangle is drawn in Quadrant II.
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) node[anchor=north west]{$A$} (3.5,0)  coordinate (B) node[below]{$B$} (120:5)coordinate(C) node[blue,above left]{$C$};
\draw[red] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

% The point C' = C is placed using Cartesian coordinates.
\coordinate (C') at (-2.5,{5*sin(120)});
\coordinate (A') at (-2.5,0);
\draw[fill] (C') circle (1.5pt);
\draw (A)--(C')--(B)--cycle;

% Angles:
\tkzMarkAngle[label=$\theta$,dist=.6,size=0.4,font=\footnotesize](B,A,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[dash dot,label=$\pi-\theta$,dist=0.95,size=0.6,font=\footnotesize](C,A,A')
\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,A',A)
\draw[dashed] (C')--(A');

% Braces indicating the distances that C' is from the axes are typeset. To give
% them the appearance of being typeset over the axes, they are first typeset
% in white with a line width of 2pt, which is 10 times the thickness of the
% brace that is actually typeset.    
\draw[white,line width=5pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=4pt,amplitude=5pt}] (A')--(C');
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt}] (A')--(C');
\draw[white,line width=5pt,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=4pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (A')--(A);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (A')--(A);

\coordinate (label_for_5_sin_theta) at ($({5*cos(120)},{2.5*sin(120)}) + (-2.5mm-10pt,0pt)$);
\node[anchor=east] at (label_for_5_sin_theta){$r\sin\theta$};
\coordinate (label_for_5_cos_theta) at (-1.25,-2.5mm-10pt);
\node at (label_for_5_cos_theta){$r\cos\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Switch `$\theta$` and `$\pi - \theta$` and have `$\pi - \theta$` at 6mm.  I really want  to know why the commands that I have for placing `A`, and the two angles are misinterpreted.

Comment: Replace `4mm` with `6mm` in your command `\draw[draw=blue,dash dot] (A) ++(180:4mm) arc (180:120:4mm);`.

Comment: You are right.  I just edited my code to have `\coordinate (label_for_theta) at (60:6.5mm);` and `\coordinate (label_for_supplement_to_theta) at (150:8.5mm);`.

Comment: Why are the commands that I have for placing A and the two angles misinterpreted?

Comment: @user74973 This is because your are drawing a normal picture inside a plot axes which where meant to be used for plotting math functions. The axes are drawn completely in the first quadrant, that is why you see things in the III quadrant.

Comment: I would prefer not to use the axis environment for such displays. Can you tell me the exact position that the `x` is typeset in the command `xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west}` and the exact position that the `y` is typeset in the command `ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}`? I do not know what the manual is saying about ticklabel*.

Comment: If I were to replace the x-axis in the `axis` environment with the command `\draw[latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0);`, where would I place the node `\node at (blah){$x$}`?

Comment: I would like to have `\coordinate (x-label) at ($(5,0) +(x-shift,y-shift)$);` and `\node at (x-label){$x$};`.  What would be the `x-shift` and `y-shift`?

Comment: @user74973 It is `\coordinate (x-label) at ($(5,0) +(.3333em,-.3333em)$);` Unless you set `inner sep=another value`, so, it is equal to the `inner sep` (which is initially `.3333em`).

Comment: I removed the `axis` environment from my code and replaced it with `\draw[latex-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0);`,
`\coordinate (x-label) at ($(5,0) +(0.3333em,-0.3333em)$);` and `\node at (x-label){$x$};` for the x-axis, and `\draw[latex-latex] (0,-5) -- (0,5);`,
`\coordinate (y-label) at ($(0,5) +(0.3333em,0.3333em)$);`, and
`\node at (y-label){$y$};` for the y-axis.  The typesettings of the `x` and `y` are closer to the arrowheads in the `TikZ` environment than in the `axis` environment.  When I replace `0.3333em` with `0.6666em`, it seems to give me the same "relative" positions.

Comment: The x-axis is longer in the `axis` environment, though.  It is harder to make a comparison when the x-axes are drawn with different lengths.  Why would they be drawn differently?  (I removed the `enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm}` specification.)

Comment: @user74973 See my code snippet in the answer box. The axes are the same and also the labels! Please run and tell me.

Comment: It seems to me that in your code showing only the display of the axes, you used both the `axis` environment and `TikZ` commands, and since only one pair of axes is drawn, the codes give the same display.  Is that correct?   So, for example, `ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}` typesets the `y` in the same spot that the `TikZ` command `\coordinate (y-label) at ($(0,5) +(0.3333em,0.3333em)$);` and `\node at (y-label){$y$};` do.  Is that correct?

Comment: @user74973 Welcome back. Yes, you 're correct. See also the PGF 3.0.0 manual Sec. 17.2.3 page 220 for details. Since the site is designed for single-focus questions, I suggest you accept one of the answers here so as not to leave the question unanswered, and feel free to open as many new questions as you wish for the benefit of the readers.

Comment: To continue our discussion, see "Drawing and labeling the axes for the Cartesian plane."  Thanks.

Comment: You should probably point out that the documentation you link to is only of use if you read French. I realise we don't say that for English-only documentation but the fact that we're answering in English already presumes readers' ability to read it. Personally, the `tkz-euclide` stuff is useless to me and I would never use it for just this reason. (This is not a criticism of the package: I wish I could read French. But I can't.)

Answer (score 3):

Another short solution (run with `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf`):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-plot}
\def\iTheta{120} \def\Radius{5} \def\Pb{4}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-1.5)(6.6,6)
  \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linecolor=black!40]{<->}(0,0)(-5,-1.5)(6.2,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \pstTriangle[linewidth=1.5pt,linejoin=2](0,0){A}(\Pb,0){B}(\Radius;\iTheta){C} 
  \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none,PointName=none](C|{0,0}){C'}
  \psline[linestyle=dashed](C)(C')\pstRightAngle[linestyle=dashed]{C}{C'}{A}
  \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=0.6]{B}{A}{C}{$\theta$}
  \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=0.6,linestyle=dotted]{C}{A}{C'}{$\pi-\theta$}
  \psbrace[ref=c,nodesepB=5pt,rot=90,braceWidth=0.5pt](C')(A){$r\cos\theta$}
  \psbrace[ref=r,nodesepA=-5pt,rot=180,braceWidth=0.5pt](C)(C'){$r\sin\theta$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution where the drawing is adjusted according to value of `\Angle` (which is denoted `\theta` on the drawing):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{xfp}

%%% Parameter %%%
\def\Angle{120} % angle (calculated counterclockwise), measured in degrees, with \Angle != 90

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-1.5)(6.6,6)
  % points
  \pnodes{P}(0,0)(5,0)(\fpeval{5*cos(\Angle*pi/180)},\fpeval{5*sin(\Angle*pi/180)})(\fpeval{5*cos(\Angle*pi/180)},0)
  % axes
  \psaxes[ticks = none, labels = none]{->}(0,0)(-5,-1.5)(6.2,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  % vertices
  \psdots(P1)(P2)
  % triangle
  \psline(P1)(P2)(P0)
  % projection onto x-axis
  \psline[linestyle = dashed, dash = 3pt 2pt](P2)(P3)
  % names of vertices
  \uput[270](P1){$B$}
  \uput[\Angle](P2){$C$}
\ifdim \Angle pt > 90 pt
  \uput[315](P0){$A$}
  \psbrace[ref = c, rot = 90, nodesepB = 5pt, braceWidth = \pslinewidth](P3)(P0){$r\cos\theta$}
  \psbrace[ref = r, rot = 180, nodesepA = -5pt, braceWidth = \pslinewidth](P2)(P3){$r\sin\theta$}
\else
  \uput[225](P0){$A$}
  \psbrace[ref = c, rot = 90, nodesepB = 5pt, braceWidth = \pslinewidth](P0)(P3){$r\cos\theta$}
  \psbrace[ref = r, nodesepA = 30pt, braceWidth = \pslinewidth](P3)(P2){$r\sin\theta$}
\fi
  % angles
  \psarc(P0){0.5}{0}{\Angle}
  \uput{0.6}[\fpeval{\Angle/2}](P0){$\theta$}
  \psarc[linestyle = dashed, dash = 3pt 2pt](P0){0.5}{\Angle}{180}
  \uput{0.5}[\fpeval{(\Angle+180)/2}](P0){$\pi - \theta$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it fairly simple...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex, line join=round,
  brace/.style={decorate, decoration={brace, raise=5pt, amplitude=5pt}}]
\draw [help lines, <->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node [at end, right] {$x$};
\draw [help lines, <->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node [at end, right] {$y$};
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) (3,0) coordinate (B) (120:4) coordinate (C);
\draw (A) node [below right] {$A$} -- (B) node [below right] {$B$} -- 
      (C) node [above left]  {$C$} -- cycle;
\fill (C) circle [radius=1pt];
\draw [dashed] (C) -- (C |- A) coordinate (C');
\pic ["$\theta$", draw, angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle=B--A--C};
\pic ["$\pi-\theta$", draw, densely dotted, angle eccentricity=2] 
  {angle=C--A--C'};
\draw [dashed] (C') ++(0,0.25) -| ++(0.25, -0.25);
\draw [brace] (A)  -- (C') node [midway, below=10pt] {$r\cos\theta$};
\draw [brace] (C') -- (C)  node [midway, left=10pt]  {$r\sin\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]